# How to compare values from dataframe and to replace them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A B C
Ex Img false
Ex Img false
Ex2 Img false
Ex3 Img false
Ex4 Img2 false
Ex5 Img3 false
```

I need to compare the values of the dataframe when the column A is equal to 'Ex', to find the value of the column B and to make the column C equal to true for the values found in B.
Like:

```
A B C
Ex Img true 
Ex Img true 
Ex2 Img true 
Ex3 Img true 
Ex3 Img2 false
Ex4 Img2 false
Ex5 Img3 false
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare values by `Ex` and pass to [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df['C'] = df.A.eq('Ex').groupby(df.B).transform('any')
```

Or filter matched groups `B` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['C'] = df.B.isin(df.loc[df.A.eq('Ex'), 'B'])
print (df)
    A     B      C
0   Ex   Img   True
1   Ex   Img   True
2  Ex2   Img   True
3  Ex3   Img   True
4  Ex4  Img2  False
5  Ex5  Img3  False
```